# Error:Failed to resolve: appcompat-v7 in android studio 3.0.1

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am facing this issue, I have done the all mandatory changes , but still facing 
[image: this issue]

build.gradle (project level)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle (app level)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/'
    }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.kiran.example.ebitcoin"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true //support color.xml colors in vector image
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility 1.8
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
    }

    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    // for EncodingUtils.getBytes(post_Data, "base64") in actrivitypaymentfrowebview

    sourceSets { main { res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res', 'src/main/assets/font'] } }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.0.4'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:27.0.1'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.1'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.2@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.flurry.android:analytics:11.0.0@aar'//flurry sdk of yahoo for crashalytics

    //compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    //compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.0.1'
    //compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.0.1'
    //compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:27.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.1'
    //to store object in shared pref
    // compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    // Retrofit
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    // JSON Parsing
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'

    //add ripple below API 21
    //compile 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
    //add this dependency to scan QR code
    compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.4.0'
    //material dialog
    // compile 'me.drakeet.materialdialog:library:1.3.1'
    //for setting GIF image
    //compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.8'
    //for material dialogs
    //implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.6.0'
    //for sms otp
    //compile 'com.github.GoodieBag:Pinview:v1.3'

    //PayUMoney
    /* compile('com.payumoney.sdkui:plug-n-play:1.1.0') {
        transitive = true;
        exclude module: 'payumoney-sdk'
    }
    compile 'com.payumoney.core:payumoney-sdk:7.1.0'*/
    //for payment gateway
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    //enable multiple methods
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    //contry code selector
    //implementation 'com.hbb20:ccp:2.1.4'

    //appling font library to app
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.2.0'

    //file compression
    compile 'id.zelory:compressor:2.1.0'
    //async task test
    //compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
   // compile 'cz.msebera.android:httpclient:4.3.6'//upload images to api using this
    //progress dialog
    //compile 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:0.4'

    //to load
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
    implementation files('libs/android-async-http-1.4.9.jar')
    implementation files('libs/android-async-http-1.4.9.jar')
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: What happens if you add `google()` to your app-level `repositories`?

Comment: Delete build caches wrapper of .gradle, delete .idea,app.iml of project.

Comment: I was able to resolve this issue by rolling back to gradle version 4.3

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all `support` lib have same version.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple reasons Why you are getting this error,

First one May be your internet is not working properly because as i see you have used a lots of third party libraries so it will require high speed internet to download.

Second one is may be your project setting is in offline mode Check it by go to File -> Settings -> Build , execution , Development and click Gradle and check weather the "Offline" work checkbox is checked or not.

Third one is may be a cache memory just invalidate and restart the project go to File ->  Invalidate Caches / Restart.

Hope this help